In a Form's Section, how to automatically dismiss the keyboard when clicking a NavigationLink to enter a child view？
The main view contains a Form with multiple Sections, including TextFields and NavigationLinks. I used an @FocusState variable to automatically pop up the keyboard when entering the main view, making it easier for users to input content directly in the TextField.
However, when I keep the keyboard open and click a NavigationLink in the Section to enter a child view, I can't find a way to automatically dismiss the keyboard upon entering the child view. I've seen several official Apple apps, like Reminders, achieve this.
Not dismissing the keyboard causes it to automatically pop up again when returning to the main view, along with triggering a "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints" error in the console.
I asked GPT for help, but the suggestions, like using simultaneousGesture or adding isActive to the NavigationLink (which might be deprecated), haven't worked. Has anyone in iOS development encountered this issue?
ensure the keyboard does not pop up again when returning to the main view.
Here's the demo code.
import SwiftUI

struct SwiftUIView: View {
    @State private var text = ""
    @FocusState private var isTextFieldFocused: Bool

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Form {
                Section {
                    TextField("Enter something", text: $text)
                        .focused($isTextFieldFocused)
                }
                
                Section {
                    NavigationLink(destination: Text("11")) {
                        HStack {
                            Label {
                                Text("subview")
                            } icon : {
                                ZStack {
                                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 6)
                                        .foregroundColor(.orange)
                                        .frame(width: 30, height: 30)

                                    Image(systemName: "face.smiling")
                                        .foregroundColor(.white)

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SwiftUIView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SwiftUIView()
    }
}


Try this approach using .onAppear for both the main view and the destination view. This will popup the keyboard when SwiftUIView first appears, and it will dismiss the keyboard when you go back to it from the child view.
Example code:
struct SwiftUIView: View {
    @State private var text = ""
    @FocusState private var isTextFieldFocused: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Form {
                Section {
                    TextField("Enter something", text: $text)
                        .focused($isTextFieldFocused)
                }
                
                Section {
                    NavigationLink(destination:
                                    Text("11")
                        .onAppear {
                            isTextFieldFocused = false // <--- here
                        }
                    ) {
                        HStack {
                            Label {
                                Text("subview")
                            } icon : {
                                ZStack {
                                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 6)
                                        .foregroundColor(.orange)
                                        .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                                    
                                    Image(systemName: "face.smiling")
                                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                                    
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .onAppear {
                isTextFieldFocused = true  // <--- here
            }
        }
    }
}

Note, you could also try using .onDisappear on the destination view.
In this case I found that the keyboard is visible for a short time, then disappears.

It really worked! I had previously tried onDisappear()  on Section or Form, and also used .simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded {}), but neither had any effect. Why does using onAppear() in the child view work? What is the underlying reason behind this?

if my answer helped you, consider accepting it, by ticking the tick mark next to it, it turns green. The reason it works is simply because isTextFieldFocused = false. Note, .onDisappear also works for me with a slight delay.

Another question is, can the keyboard be prevented from automatically popping up when returning from the NavigationLink?

...can the keyboard be prevented from automatically popping up when returning from the NavigationLink? Yes, use my code, it will popup
the keyboard when SwiftUIView first appears, and it
will dismiss the keyboard when you go back to it from the NavigationLink.
